# Kmeans clustering in Octave-- problems with Plotting multiple variables on one axis vs. normalized value, as well as overlaying new data on old data

Tags: plot, octave, k-means

***Background Information:***

I am developing a kmeans algorithm with multiple variables, and I am struggling with the concept of plotting all of the variables on the same graph together. The data set contains a set of statistics from baseball-- the columns are: Player, BA, OPS, RBI, and OBP.

This is what the first few rows of my data set look like from my CSV file(out of 411 rows):

```
Player,BA,OPS,RBI,OBP
SandyAlcantara,0.086,0.22,4,0.117
PeteAlonso,0.26,0.941,120,0.358
BrandonLowe,0.27,0.85,51,0.336
MikeSoroka,0.077,0.22,3,0.143
```

In order to make this work, however I actually made a new file (called MLBn.txt), which had the first row and first column removed, so that there were no string values when scaling them.

This is what that looked like:

```
0.086   0.22    4   0.117
0.26    0.941   120 0.358
0.27    0.85    51  0.336
0.077   0.22    3   0.143
0.233   0.774   25  0.324
0.329   0.852   19  0.381
0.287   0.785   17  0.325
0.271   0.82    77  0.34
0.207   0.691   13  0.324
```

I used this code (in a separate file) to scale the values:

```
    function dataout = scaledata(datain,minval,maxval)
  dataout = datain - min(datain(:));
  dataout = (dataout/range(dataout(:)))*(maxval-minval);
  dataout = dataout + minval;
  end
```

The resulting output of this looked as such:
in command window:

```
load MLBn.txt
dataout = scaledata(MLBn, -1,1);
```

[image]

***Here is where my problem begins***

With this data, I wanted to create a function where the user is able to input new values, and have their values be combined with the existing data file so that the user is able to see where the inputted values are clustered in reference to the existing data. My attempt at that code is here:

```
### define function where user can input new data for rookie players

 function newKmeansData([OPS BatAv OBP RBI])
   
###combine new matrix and old matrix for k means and plotting purposes
   [v1,v2] = meshgrid (newdata, dataout)
   
   totaldata = [v1(:),v2(:)] 
           
###scale data

load MLBn.txt
dataout = scaledata(totaldata, -1,1);
```

I used this next algorithm to cluster and plot the data *BEFORE* introducing that problematic function above, and was able to create an actual graph with some points, though it seems problematic in itself:

```
### cluster the data 
K = 3
[idx,centers] = kmeans(dataout,K);


### Plot the result
 figure;
 plot (dataout (idx==1, 1), dataout (idx==1, 2), 'ro', 'MarkerSize',10);
 hold on;
 plot (dataout (idx==2, 1), dataout (idx==2, 2), 'bs', 'MarkerSize',10);
 plot (centers (:, 1), centers (:, 2), 'kv', 'MarkerSize', 14, 'LineWidth', 3)
 legend('Cluster 1','Cluster 2','Centroids','Location','NW')
title ('Input Value Compared to Allstar Data')
xlabel('Hitter Statistics')
ylabel('Standardized Data Scale')
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',{'OPS','BatAv','OBP','RBI'})

 hold off;
```

Here is the graph that code created:
[image: Plot of clusters with no user input]

***ULTIMATE QUESTION***

My problem I feel is that I am incorrectly scaling the plot, and just not labeling everything properly in the graph. I feel as though I should probably separately normalize and plot the new user inputted data on top of the old data in a different shape or color, just I am not sure how to go about doing that.

Is there a way to assign each variable from my data set to its own x-axis tick mark, and plot it against the normalized values, so that the user is able to view what the specific stats look like from each player?

***Some Ideas I had for this:***

I could try to define the columns as the various labels I intended

```
#like the cell2table function
C = {MLBn}
T = cell2table(C,...
    'VariableNames',{'BA' 'OPS' 'RBI' 'OBP'})
```

Or involve the new data by just plotting separately

```
   figure;
     plot (newdata (idx==1, 1), newdata (idx==1, 2), 'ro', 'MarkerSize',5);
     hold on;
     plot (newdata (idx==2, 1), newdata (idx==2, 2), 'bs', 'MarkerSize',5);
     plot (dataout (idx==1, 1), dataout (idx==1, 2), '*', 'MarkerSize',5);
     hold on;
     plot (dataout (idx==2, 1), dataout (idx==2, 2), '.', 'MarkerSize',5);
```

Any guidance or help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Danijel, sorry you haven't had any replies yet. I don't want to add insult to injury, but I think the sheer length of this question makes it very unlikely to get answered. There is an art to asking questions that make people want to have a go at them. In the immortal words of Saitama the One-punch-man: "can you summarize it to 20 words or less?". I admit I've read your question twice and still have no idea what it is exactly that you want. Maybe you can replace unnecessary details with a "this is what I want" rough sketch?